# How to replace all characters in string that don't match a pattern in sed?

Tags: sed, command, pattern-matching

I have a string such as "something_something_something"

Now the string must have the pattern: `^[a-zA-Z0-9](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*`

How can I replace all characters in the string that don't match the pattern?

For my example, I should have:

`somethingsomethingsomething`

I tried `sed -n '/^[a-zA-Z0-9](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*/p'` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you need `sed -E`, so that the pattern is interpreted as an extended regex (ERE), and the plain parenthesis work for grouping. By default, sed's pattern is a basic regex (BRE), and you'd need to use `\(` and `\)`.

Second, `sed -n '/.../p'` works, but of course prints the whole line if part of it matches. If your pattern was anchored at the end, too, then deleting the whole line would be useful.

If you want to remove the part that doesn't fit the pattern, you could do something like this:

```
sed -E -e 's/^([a-zA-Z0-9](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*).*/\1/' input.txt
```

The trailing `.*` makes sure the whole line is matched, and everything is then replaced with what's in the first capture group. With the input `something_something_something`, this would print `something`, since `_` isn't matched by the main part of the pattern.

Note that your pattern looks like it would be equivalent to just `[-a-zA-Z0-9]+`. Perhaps you mean something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` instead? That should match strings like `foo` or `foo-bar-doodoo` (but not `foo--bar`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess, is it possible to use sed to instead replace all invalid characters that dont match the patterns with an empty space?

Answer (score 0):

We compose another regex, stored in the shell var named sNr (Search n Replace),
where we add on to your something regex you quoted.

We shall be replacing any non - something character as a hash (#).

```
sNr='
 s@
  \(
   \(
    \(
      [a-zA-Z0-9](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*
    \)\{1,\}
    #*
  \)*
 \)
 [^a-zA-Z0-9#]
 @\1#@
';

echo something_something_something |
sed -e "
  :loop
    ${sNr//[$IFS]/}
  tloop
"
something#something#something
```